# To define two random variables that satisfy a condition

Tags: probability-theory

**First:**

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}$ be 4 random variables.Consider the two auxiliary random variables: $\tilde{X_{1}}, \tilde{X_{2}}$ where their corresponding alphabets $\tilde{\chi_{1}}, \tilde{\chi_{2}}$ equal respectively the alphabets of $X_{1}, X_{2}$.

---

**The problem:**

The text then define the auxiliary random variables to be 2 random variables such that the joint distribution of the 6 random variables is defined by:

> $$p_{1234\tilde{1}\tilde{2}}(x_{1}, x_{2},x_{3}, x_{4},\tilde{x_{1}}, \tilde{x_{2}}) =\left\{\begin{array}{c c}\dfrac{p_{1234}(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4})p_{1234}(\tilde{x_{1}},\tilde{x_{2}}, x_{3},x_{4})}{p_{34}(x_{3},x_{4})}, &  p_{34}(x_{3},x_{4})\neq 0\\
>        0, & p_{34}(x_{3},x_{4})= 0
>      \end{array}\right.$$

**My problem/confusion is:** How can I be sure that this is indeed possible? How can I be sure that there exist such random variables $\tilde{\chi_{1}}, \tilde{\chi_{2}}$ that satisfy this condition?

Comment: Bounties are allright but the present one is ending in 2 days and nothing happened, hence you might also want to indicate which parts of your question, if any, have not received a satisfactory answer yet (I confess being interested in this piece of information, having written an answer). Until now, your reactions to the efforts made to answer your question have been nonexistent, except that you proposed a bounty with the ready-made motive that "This question has not received enough attention"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,Y)$ be defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Consider $\bar\Omega=\Omega\times\Omega$ endowed with the product sigma-algebra $\bar{\mathcal F}=\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal F$ and the probability measure $\mathbb P=P\otimes P$. Consider $\bar X$, $\bar Y$, $\bar Z$ and $\bar T$ defined on $\bar\Omega$ by $\bar X(\omega_1,\omega_2)=X(\omega_1)$, $\bar Y(\omega_1,\omega_2)=Y(\omega_1)$, $\bar Z(\omega_1,\omega_2)=X(\omega_2)$, and $\bar T(\omega_1,\omega_2)=Y(\omega_2)$. Now:

> If $X$ is distributed like your $(X_1,X_2)$, if $Y$ is distributed like your $(X_3,X_4)$, and if $(X,Y)$ is distributed like your $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$, then $(\bar X,\bar Y,\bar Z)$ conditioned on $\bar Y=\bar T$ is distributed like your $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,\tilde X_1,\tilde X_2)$.

To sum up, one may have to enlarge the sample space but one can indeed define $(\tilde X_1,\tilde X_2)$ whose joint distribution with $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is as you described.

Answer (score 0):

As Did pointed out, you may need to refine your probability space.

One way to think about this problem is as follows. You first sample your random variables $X_1, \dots, X_4$. Then you sample $\tilde X_1$ and $\tilde X_2$ form a distribution with density 
$$p_{1234}(\tilde x_1,\tilde x_2, X_3, X_4) / p_{34}(X_3,X_4)$$
(here, $X_3$ and $X_4$ are the values from your first sample). Note that this is a valid distribution since all numbers $p_{1234}(\tilde x_1,\tilde x_2, X_3, X_4) / p_{34}(X_3,X_4)$ are non-negative, and $\sum_{\tilde x_1,\tilde x_2} p_{1234}(\tilde x_1,\tilde x_2, X_3, X_4) / p_{34}(X_3,X_4) = 1$. We get r.v. $X_1,X_2,X_3, X_4,\tilde X_1, \tilde X_4$. Their joint distribution is 
$$p_{1234}(x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4) \times \frac{p_{1234}(\tilde x_1,\tilde x_2, x_3, x_4)}{p_{34}(x_3,x_4)},$$
as required.